# Enable HDMI audio on RPi 2 with IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, hdmi

Is it possible to enable HDMI audio when running an UWP app on RPi 2? There is sound when I connect speakers via the 3.5mm jack, but I would prefer HDMI audio.

Apparently it's possible, but I don't know how to do it on IoT Core: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI audio is **not** supported on Windows 10 IoT for the Raspberry Pi. The only option available is the 3.5mm headphone jack.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn914597(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The link content has now been updated, can't find the information anymore.